# Custom Policy - pre-create Local Account to link with Federated User but prevent login if AccountEnabled == false

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm trying to create a variation of [this sample code](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/link-local-account-with-federated-account) which links a Federated login against a pre-created Local Account. I have this working and I'm happy with it so far!

I'm synchronising users from an Azure AD via a SCIM endpoint (that utilises Microsoft Graph). When a user is removed from the Enerprise Application, then an update happens that marks the user as inactive. This in turn updates the Local Account in B2C and sets `accountEnabled` to `false`.

What I would like to do is prevent the Federated User from logging into our app if the Local Account is marked as disabled. So here's what I've implemented in `TrustFrameworkExtension.xml`:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingUserIdentity">
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="api-version">1.6</Item>
    <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
    <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
    <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">User does not exist. Please sign up before you can sign in.</Item>
    <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Your account has been locked. Contact your support person to unlock it, then try again.</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userIdentities" PartnerClaimType="userIdentities" Required="true" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <!-- Required claims -->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userIdentities" />
    
    <!-- Optional claims -->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountEnabled" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="ExtractIssuers" />
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertAccountEnabledIsTrue" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Most of it is the same as the original, I've just added the `accountEnabled` claim, the `AssetAccountEnabledIsTrue` output claim transformation and the `UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual` message.

This has introduced the desired behaviour - even if the user successfully logs in as the Federated User, if the Local Account is disabled an exception is thrown and User Journey ends.

However, when access is denied in our app, I get the following output:

```
Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID: 00-ce99c54f1630a4453e6ec447a18de5f6-f4bef2eedac9fd1d-00

Details
Message contains error: 'server_error', error_description: 'AADB2C: An exception has occurred. Correlation ID: 017cb7bd-4291-4b62-aa78-46213a53f927 Timestamp: 2022-06-07 09:34:02Z ', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.
```

I was hoping that it would include the message from `UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual` in the output. Is it because I'm not utilising the `AssertAccountEnabledIsTrue` Techical Profile properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/boolean-transformations#assertbooleanclaimisequaltovalue), the error message needs to be in a self-asserted TP.

"The AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue claims transformation is always executed from a validation technical profile that is called by a self-asserted technical profile".

Comment: Is there an example of implementing "Federated login against a pre-created Local Account" with the ability to prevent a federated user logging from logging in if the Local Account is disabled? I'm really struggling with grokking/customising Custom Policies

Comment: In order to do this, you have to link the two accounts. There's a sample - https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/link-local-account-with-federated-account - and I did a post on this - https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-identities-and-linking-them-in-azure-ad-b2c-33b72fcbfd25. Both identities now point to the same B2C user. Basically, when the user logs in with a federated account, you do a ReadUsingAlternativeSecurityID instead of a ReadUsingEmail. Then you do "AssertAccountEnabledIsTrue".

Comment: You can tell the difference as to how they log in because in federated login, objectID doesn't exist. - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/main/SocialAndLocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L1080

Comment: In the sample would you put the "AssertAccountEnabledIsTrue" after step 3 (AAD-FindB2CUserWithAADOid) or step 8 (AAD-UserReadUsingUserIdentity-NoError)

Comment: Neither. That sample is to link the identities. For login, use the link above i.e. the "SignUpOrSignIn" user journey. Remove steps 4 & 6. Add "AssertAccountEnabledIsTrue" just before the SendClaims.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/main/SocialAndLocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L1080

Comment: Thanks, eventually I figured out what you meant! I know this isn't the right place for it but I'm trying to pre-link an account (i.e. avoid the sign up process). If I start with the link you gave me, am I on the right track?

Comment: Start a new question with your use case. Hard to answer in the comments :-)

Comment: I've created a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72639209/federated-sign-in-no-sign-up-process). Hopefully it provides the appropriate context!