# Federated sign in, no sign up process

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

With regards to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72531339/custom-policy-pre-create-local-account-to-link-with-federated-user-but-prevent). The following (hopefully) clarifies the context.

I'm trying to create a user journey for a multi-tenant application. To begin with, at least, users will belong to an Azure AD. I'm creating a SCIM endpoint (utilising Microsoft Graph) that will synchronise authorised users in our Azure B2C Directory.

This would be the process for authorised users:

1. Users are added/authorised to an appropriately configured Enterprise Application in the customers Azure AD
2. Users are created in our Azure B2C Directory via our SCIM endpoint utilising Microsoft Graph (similar to the script in [this sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/link-local-account-with-federated-account))
3. A user from the customers Azure AD can then go to our application and attempt to login. There will be a button there for them to login via their federated account
4. Once they have successfully logged in using their Azure AD account, then it will be matched to their pre-generated Local Account and linked
5. Login is successful and the application is given an id token

In the case where the user isn't authorised/synchronised yet:

1. SCIM synchronisation does not occur
2. The user goes to our application and attempts to login. They click the button to login via the Federated account
3. Once they have successfully logged in using their Azure AD account, then there is no match with a Local Account
4. Login is not successful. The user is returned to the login page with an error message telling them to contact their System Administrator with regards to access

However, the SCIM endpoint can be used to deactivate users. What I would like to do is deny access if the Local Account exists, but it is disabled. So, in the case that the user has been disabled:

1. The Azure AD admin removes the user from the Enterprise Application
2. Users that are removed are updated via the SCIM endpoint. In our code, at the moment, we set `accountEnabled` on the Local Account to `false`
3. A disabled user goes to our application and attempts to login. They click the button to login via their federated account
4. Once they have successfully logged in using their Azure AD account, then there is a match with their Local Account
5. However, since this account is disabled, then login is not successful. Ideally, they would be returned to the login page with an error message stating that their account is disabled

At this stage I'm assuming that access to our application will be exclusively via Azure AD Federated accounts. I'm thinking that I might even remove the username/password text boxes on the login page, to make things more obvious to the end user.

However, there is the issue of 3rd parties. Our website is an Asset Management system for Bridges and Roads. Local Councils will employ consultants (the 3rd party) to carry out Inspections on their behalf. So I need to consider how they will be given access to the system. In the worst case, they will be given a Local Account with a username and password.

There will definitely be no self sign-up process.

Given the above, what would you recommend as a starting point and is there any advice you can provide to achieve my goal? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only allow accounts that have been pre created for login via external IdP:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/link-local-account-with-federated-account

Prevent federated accounts which have been disabled from logging on:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/disable-social-account-from-logon

Comment: A question @JasSuri. The two policies above use different attributes for accountEnabled. The federation one uses extension_accountEnabled. The way the use case reads, the federated account needs to use accountEnabled as well. After linking, if ReadUsingAlternativeSecurityID also read accountEnabled, then the same code could be used to block both local and federated?

Comment: Yes, you could just use one attribute.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I had attempted to apply the `AAD-DisabledUserPage` to the link account sample. I had omitted the `dummy` claim and that page was never displayed - which lead to my initial confusion in the linked post

Comment: However, I do have a question about the customisation of the disabled page. Which is over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72653603/custom-behaviour-for-selfasserted-content)

Comment: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/linking-a-federated-login-against-an-existing-azure-ad-b2c-local-account-ea2db2fc2252