# Custom behaviour for selfAsserted content?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Following this [disabled social account from logon sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/disable-social-account-from-logon). Here's what I see when the Local Account user exists and is disabled:

[image: Dummy/disabled user page]

*NB - I've changed the `ContentDefinition` so that it's using `2.1.7` instead of `1.1.0`.*

I'm assuming the "hide me" text box is to be hidden using css? Which would mean that I would have to implement my own Template?

Also, there's a Cancel and a Continue button. Because the `dummy` textbox doesn't actually do anything, clicking the Continue button does not work. So I assume I want to hide the Continue button, but only when the `dummy` text box is present? Does that mean I should be looking at Javascript?

Finally, the `UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual` error message (defined in the `AAD-DisabledUserPage` Technical Profile) does not appear anywhere in the source of the page. It seems integral to the strategy in the sample. Am I missing something?

I've looked at [Customise the UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui?pivots=b2c-custom-policy), [Customise the UI with HTML template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) and [Enable JavaScript and page layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy). There doesn't seem to be anything on customising the generated content. Have I missed something in the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very strange so I had a look at the sample.

This is an old sample. It still uses "socialIdpUserId".

```
<! - The claim socialIdpUserId has been renamed to issuerUserId →
```

I renamed this in the base file to "issuerUserId".

Essentially, they needed a "dead-end" page.

But the dead-end page needs an output claim so they made a dummy one but wanted in removed!

I would have used a [paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema#paragraph) element. Maybe it wasn't available then?

I wrote [that up](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/creating-an-error-page-for-an-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy-flow-fb2692a3b50f) a while back.

My version is in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/rbrayb/619246c281f3cf3c519aaf856a5e940a).

If disabled, the user sees:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can hide Cancel and Continue by modifying the technical profile. See the **Metadata** section [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile).